# PHPUnit: how to submit raw data to post request linking for testing in Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, lumen

I am using the default PHPUnit that comes with Lumen. While I am able to create a mock post call to my link, I am unable to find a way to feed raw data to it.

Currently, to mock up JSON input, from [official document](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/master/testing#testing-json-apis), I can:

```
     $this->json('POST', '/user', ['name' => 'Sally'])
         ->seeJson([
            'created' => true,
         ]);
```

Or if I want simple form input, I can:

```
    $this->post('/user', ['name' => 'Sally'])
         ->seeJsonEquals([
            'created' => true,
         ]);
```

Is there a way I can insert raw body content to the post request? (Or at least a request with XML input? This is a server to receive callback from WeChat, where we have no choice but forced to use XML as WeChat wanted to use.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use Laravel's \`call\` method to send raw JSON data in a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555972/can-i-use-laravels-call-method-to-send-raw-json-data-in-a-unit-test)

Comment: Although that question ask for a way to send raw JSON, the answers just suggest using the first method I mentioned in my post to send out JSON. The problem is that now I need to handle XML and this is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/master/testing#application-testing) if you want to create a custom HTTP request you can use the `call` method:

> If you would like to make a custom HTTP request into your application
>   and get the full Illuminate\Http\Response object, you may use the call
>   method:

```
public function testApplication()
{
    $response = $this->call('GET', '/');

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
}
```

Here is the [call](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/6.x/src/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php#L376) method:

```
public function call($method, $uri, $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null)
```

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
$this->call('POST', '/user', [], [], [], ['Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF8'], $xml);
```

To access the data in your controller you can use the following:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $xml = $request->getContent();
    // Or you can use the global request helper
    $xml = request()->getContent();
}
```

Comment: While it seems to be the answer, I cannot get the content when I do `dd(file_get_contents('php://input'));` In the code being tested. It simply returns empty. I am using Lumen 5.4, but I have checked the source code that the call() function should be the same for Lumen 5.4 too.

Comment: @cytsunny I updated my answer on how you can retrieve the data from the request, could you try it.

Comment: Um.... in other words, to have my code tested, not only I have to write a test code, but I also need to change the code being tested? I have tested that it works, but that doesn't feel right.

Comment: @cytsunny I mean you could figure out why `file_get_contents('php://input')` is empty and fix it so you could use your code, but I don't see a reason to not use the tools the framework provides for you.

Comment: @cytsunny check that there aren't any redirects within either the server, or the application. php://input will be missing data in that case according to documentation (that includes HTACCESS rewrite rules)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov While I understand your explanation, I thought there should be some way to simulate it?

Comment: @cytsunny You can run console [CURL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102134/curl-check-redirect) with -I (upper i) and your URL, and check the headers to see if there are any redirects exist before the final URL is retrieved.